# Enabling /Disabling ButtonField of GridView using Checkbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, c#-3.0

I have grid view

- one column is ItemTemplate column which has Checkbox field.
- Other 2 columns are Databound columns. One column is ButtonField which is of Button type.

I want this button to initially set to **disabled mode**

Once the Checkbox is checked it should be **enabling** that particular row button field. Could anyone help in this?

My sample try

.aspx file

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Email_NotificationConnection %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Customer_Name] FROM [Customer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_Name" HeaderText="Customer_Name" 
                SortExpression="Customer_Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField>

            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="non_prod_all_select" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged1"  />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                      <HeaderStyle Width="30px" /></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Button" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

.aspx.cs file

```
  protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow gridrow = ((GridViewRow)(chk.Parent));
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)(gridrow.FindControl("Button"));
        btn.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Button btn = (Button)(gridrow.FindControl("Button"));
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what You tried??? What is .aspx ??? .aspx.cs...??

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I havent tried anything. Please help

Comment: try something and come up with the error mate we are here to help you not to write code for you mate

Comment: Where you get error in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code:

ASPX code for the GridView1:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Email_NotificationConnection %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Customer_Name] FROM [Customer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_Name" HeaderText="Customer_Name" 
                SortExpression="Customer_Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField>

            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="non_prod_all_select" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged1"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
             <HeaderStyle Width="30px" /></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind (for CheckBox Check Changed Event handler):

```
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
            {
                ((Button)row.FindControl("Button1")).Enabled = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("non_prod_all_select")).Checked;

            }
         }
```

Changes made:

1.Set AutoPostBack for CheckBox to true.

2.Removed Button Field and added a template field with button in the third column of the Grid (so that the asp:Button control could be read easily in code behind)

3.Changed the code behind code to do the necessary.

NOTE: I have checked this code locally and is working as expected. So just replace your old code with this and let me know in case of any issues.